# No se ha inicializado la propiedad

Tags: c#

Tengo esta cadena de conexión y este método pero al ejecutar aparece el siguiente mensaje **No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conexion" connectionString=  "Server=192.168; Password=***;user=ra;DataBase=Setup"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>


private void Cargar_registro(string codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sql);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select cedula,nombre,clave,cambioclave,autoriza from Usuarios where cedula = @cedula", con);//@parametro
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);//una coneccion y uno o mas comandos
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cedula", codigo));//adiciona parametro
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);//ejecuta una sentencia Sql
            adap.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow fila = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                txtCodigo.Text = fila["cedula"].ToString();
                txtNombre.Text = fila["nombre"].ToString();
                chkcambioclave.Checked = bool.Parse(fila["cambioclave"].ToString());
                chkautoriza.Checked = bool.Parse(fila["autoriza"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: en donde le estas pasando la cadena de conexion a con?

Comment: El mensaje sale al llegar al IF

Comment: vuelvo a preguntar.. en donde le estas pasando la cadena de conexion a con?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sql);

Comment: Si se ve que le pasas la conexion ahi, pero no se ve como inicializas esa cadena porque puede ser que estas haciendo asi : string con = string.Empty; Creo que esa es la pregunta que te esta haciendo @gbianchi